# New Relic availability monitoring for subdomains

Tags: analytics, monitoring, pinging

Does New Relic support availability monitoring for subdomains?  I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Synthetics monitor to any URL.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/synthetics/new-relic-synthetics/using-monitors/add-edit-monitors#types-monitors